# How to specify Minimized/Compact Mode for BottomAppBar WP8.1 in C# file

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

How to specify Minimized/Compact Mode for BottomAppBar WP8.1 but in the C# file?

I think that is setting the CommandBar.ClosedDisplayMode property, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a variable to the CommandBar then set the property as normal:

You can assign the variable with an x:Name in your Xaml:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="cmdBar">
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Or you can find it from the page in your code behind:

```
CommandBar cmdBar = Page.BottomAppBar as CommandBar;
```

Either way:

```
cmdBar.ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact;
```